# Programmatically create arguments to data.frame in R

Tags: r

this is probably a really stupid question, but I am big R newbie and. I have a matrix, which i need to frame. Is there a better way to do this, other than:

```
data1 = data.frame(X0 = Ytrain, X1 = Xtrain[,2], X2 = Xtrain[,3], ... , X50 = Xtrain[,51])
```

?

I was able to generate this monstrosity in Emacs, but now i need to create R function that does this. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Tomas

Comment: Could you give a little more info about `Ytrain` and `Xtrain`? You write that you have *a* matrix, which I assume is `Xtrain`. Is `Ytrain` also a matrix? Or do both objects come from one original matrix? I ask because `Ytrain` might get recycled if it is shorter than `nrow(Xtrain)`.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to mention that. Ytrain is a column vector with same amount of rows as teh Xtrain. But guys below already figured that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
# Assuming you used all the columns of `Xtrain` but the first
NEW.DF <- data.frame(Ytrain, Xtrain[, -1]) 
# If you didn't use all the cols of `xtrain`:
# NEW.DF <- data.frame(Ytrain, Xtrain[, 2:51])
names(NEW.DF) <- paste0("X", 0:(ncol(NEW.DF)-1))
```

Comment: +1 (to help you get that silver R badge....). But according to the OP, `Xtrain` starts from the second column, so you should modify your answer accordingly.

Comment: Was taking care of that as you were typing :) Thanks

Comment: not sure if it was a typo, but i had to use paste("X", 0:(ncol(NEW.DF)-1),sep="") ... no biggie, though

Comment: @Arg, the function `paste0` was added in R 2.15.0 and is equivalent to the way you used `paste`.

Comment: aha, that explains it. I use 2.14.1.

Comment: @mrdwab I see what you're saying now

Answer (score 2):

```
data1 <- cbind(data.frame(X0 = Ytrain),data.frame(Xtrain[, -1]))
```

Matrix columns are named `X1`...`XN` by default on conversion to `data.frame` unless they are already named.